# invalid composite literal type when creating struct

Tags: go

I’m not too familiar with this in Go

```
type PageOffset int
type Page int
```

How would I create an instance of a struct using `PageOffset` & `Page`?

```
type GetParams struct {
    Page *Page 
    PageOffset *PageOffset 
}
```

I've tried something like this but I am getting this error

```
invalid composite literal type


p := GetParams{}
p.Page = &Page{1}
p.PageOffset = &PageOffset{10}
```

Comment: That's because PageOffset and Page aren't composite types, so `PageOffset{}` don't make no sense. You can do `po := PageOffset(1); p.PageOffset = &po`. If you have too many places where you need to initialize pointers to these basic types then you can declare a constructor for them.

Comment: Check out the first paragraph in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators you'll see that while composite literals are included, basic type literals like integers, strings, floats, etc. aren't, which is why stuff like `&int64(10)` or `&"foo bar"` is illegal. There's a one-line option (not recommended) where you take the address of an indexing operation: `&([]PageOffset{10}[0])`, however I would suggest you keep things simple and use the two-line option to get the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Page and PageOffset are not structs but rather new type definitions with underlying int types, you should use it like when using `int` directly

```
p := Page(1)
pO := PageOffset(2)
GetParams{
  Page:       &p,
  PageOffset: &pO,
}
```

Comment: @Volker updated the answer with correct terminology